# Angular Router not updating browser URL when called from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I have an AngularJS application, which I'm in the process of converting to a hybrid Angular/AngularJS application using ngUpgrade. The AngularJS application is unusual in that it doesn't use the AngularJS or Angular UI router - instead it has its own hand-rolled navigation solution, which doesn't update the URL displayed in the browser, or interact with the browser's history API. So far, so good.

I want to start using the Angular Router in the hybrid application, but initially only for new pages.

To get the 2 parts of the application - Angular and AngularJS - interoperating with each other, I have downgraded the Angular Router service and injected it into one of my AngularJS services, so that I can call `Router.navigateByUrl()` to navigate to a new Angular page component, from my AngularJS code.

This works correctly - the Angular page component is added to my `<router-outlet>` and is displayed in the browser as expected.

Strangely though, the browser URL does not change. When I enable tracing for the Router, I can see the *new* route being correctly processed, and the *new* page is displayed in the browser, but the browser URL still shows the *old* route. Also, if I look at the browser history, the *new* route has not been added to it.

I've tried injecting `NgZone` into my AngularJS service and calling `Router.navigateByUrl()` inside `NgZone.run()`, but it doesn't make any difference.

When I call `Router.navigateByUrl()` from my Angular code, everything works fine - *except* when I do this *after* I've done it from AngularJS, when I then see the same symptoms. It's as if calling the `Router` directly from AngularJS is somehow breaking the link between the route and the browser URL bar.

Can anyone help please...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the AngularJS `$location` service wasn't being updated when the route changed, leaving a disparity between its value and the value being displayed in the browser. There was also a watch in this service which was being triggered in every digest cycle, that was then resetting the browser url from the value in the `$location` service!

Turns out this was because I needed to configure the Unified Angular Location Service in my `AppModule` viz:

```
imports: [
  LocationUpgradeModule.config()
]
```

and downgrade the `$locationShim` service for injection into AngularJS viz:

```
angularJS.module('my-app')
  .factory('$location', downgradeInjectable($locationShim));
```